# Count calls to method with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I'm trying to learn about dependency injection. I'm using .net 6.0 Razor Pages and I want to "count", the number of times a method is called via dependency injection.
My Index is as following:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public ICounter _counter;

    public IndexModel(ICounter counter)
    {
        _counter = counter;
    }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public void OnPostInfo()
    {
        Count = _counter.Calls(Count);
    }
}
```

My "counter" class, is as following

```
public int Number { get; set; }
public int Calls(int Number)
{
    return Number += 1 ;
}
```

And my interface

```
public interface ICounter
{
   int Calls(int Number);     
}
```

My Program.cs class

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICounter, Counter>();
```

My View.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        @Model.Count
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <form asp-page-handler="Info" method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Push to count</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

It's added as an Transient in Program.cs. The site is updated via a button, and that "works", but it only updates to 1. But then it stops. It doesn't continue to "2, 3, 4" etc when i push the button that uses the OnPostInfo method.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Read about the different of lifetimes (`transient`, `scoped` and `singleton`). Dependencies which are registered as `transient` are re-created every time they're accessed, thus resetting the counter every time.

Comment: @nbokmans tried with all three different. Still the same result.

Comment: @Mr.Jones - transient, scoped and singleton are relevant to the same request, i believe you have different postback requests for each time you are trying to count.

Comment: you can use singleton and in startup get the service it will create the object.

Comment: Singletons should be the same for every object and every request. If singleton doesntwork shows us how your injecting / wiring up your di container.

Comment: @Selthien updated the original post with further info about my injection and such.

Comment: Do you have warnings? `Number` property in `Counter` class is never used for example. Maybe you have some bug in current code.

Comment: You seem to have two different properties for keeping track of the count: IndexModel.Count, and Counter.Number. Seems you're getting them confused. IndexModel.Count obviously won't work because the page class is a fresh instance every time the page is hit. If you register your Counter class as a Singleton and properly call the method to increment it (and why does that increment method take a number)? then it should work. You probably could have figured this out by using your IDE's debugger.

Comment: Why does `ICounter.Calls()` have an argument at all?

Comment: The real problem here is that your test scenario for using DI is not a scenario that makes real-world sense.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, questions, and everything in between. 
I have now solved the issue with the help of Rena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not caused by lifetime. It dues to the `Count` value is not passed to the backend, so backend will always get the int default value `0` for `Count`.

You need set a hidden input or route parameter to pass the `Count`.

**First way to set a hidden input:**

View:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        @Model.Count
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <form asp-page-handler="Info" method="post">
        <input hidden asp-for="Count" value="@Model.Count" /> <!--set the hidden input-->
        <button class="btn btn-default">Push to count</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public ICounter _counter;

    public IndexModel(ICounter counter)
    {

        _counter = counter;
    }
    [BindProperty]  //add this attribute to get the Count value
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public void OnPostInfo()
    {
        Count = _counter.Calls(Count);
    }
}
```

**The second way to set a route parameter:**

View:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        @Model.Count
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">                  <!--add asp-route-countNum -->
    <form asp-page-handler="Info" asp-route-countNum="@Model.Count" method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Push to count</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public ICounter _counter;

    public IndexModel(ICounter counter)
    {

        _counter = counter;
    }

    public int Count { get; set; }
    public void OnPostInfo(int countNum)   //add parameter here
    {
        Count = _counter.Calls(countNum);   //change here... 
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]